# How can I make javascript in a column header launch javascript of all rows below it?

Tags: javascript, c#

Let me describe what I have, and then what I want.

I have a table with users and various actions that can be taken for this user. Each row has the user's name, then several columns of actions.

Each column has javascript that will perform that action for that specific users when clicked. Now, I want a column header that allows users to perform that action on all users in the results.

Here's an example:

***MY RESULTS TABLE:***

**---User's Name---Run All---Delete All---Move All---**

---John Doe----------Run--------Delete-------Move----

---Jane Doe----------Run--------Delete-------Move----

---Mike SMith--------Run--------Delete-------Move----

There is javascript for each of the links above in the rows. Clicking "Run" will perform an appropriate action, as will clicking "Delete" and "Move.

However, I want the "Run All" link to perform the task linked in each of the "Run" links below it.

Is it possible to do this? I know It can be done in the C# code behind, building up the javascript for each result into a large script, before binding it to the "Run All" link, but I'd like to see if it is possible for javascript to launch the javascript below it in a column of a table.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: This table... Is it made of HTML? Maybe you could share some code instead of just descriptions of code?

Comment: <table class="dataGridCondensed" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" rules="all" border="0" id="users_grid" style="border-width:0px;">
 <tbody><tr class="dataGridCondensed dataGridPager" align="right" style="background-color:LightGrey;">

Comment: It renders in Html. It's build in the C# code behind. Dynamic, so the table only exists when built. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am making a couple of assumptions in this example:

1. The "... All" are links and not buttons
2. The "... All" links are in the first row of the table.
3. The links are in individual cells by themselves.

Make adjustments as necessary, but I hope the following helps:

```
// bind click events to all links in the first row of the table
$(".dataGridCondensed tr").first().find("a").click(function() {

     // get the index of the column that holds the clicked link
     var col = $(this).parents("td").first().index(); 

     // find all the column's in rows after the first row (index 0) with the same index (col), and click the link in that column
     $(".dataGridCondensed tr:gt(0) td:eq(" + col + ")").find("a").click();
})
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me! I will try this solution out as well. Can't wait to see the results :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using jQuery, but it would help a lot for this use case.

```
//find rows of your table, then for each one
`$('#myTable tr').each(function(){
    var row = $(this); 
    var action = row.find('.classToDenoteTheRunAnchorTag');
    action.trigger('click');
});
```

You mentioned C#, so I assume this is ASP.NET. If each of them is going to be calling the server via ajax or something, you'd probably be better off having a single server method that it calls that iterates through them all, instead of sending many requests simultaneously from the client.

Comment: Thanks, I will ask about this. I believe we can use JQuery. Will check into this asap.